# What is a good pattern for reconnecting external databases?

Tags: go

How can I efficiently reconnect to an external database when I find out that the persistent connection is down? If `ExtClient` loses connection, it would return "Broken pipe" on `err`.

```
func ListenForWork(cmdChannel <-chan *WorkCmd) {
    for {
        cmd, ok := <- cmdChannel
        if !ok {
            break
        }
        for { // Retry request until it's OK (`Broken pipe error` might destroy it)
            _, err := ExtClient.Request(cmd.Key, cmd.Value)
            if err == nil {
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I, from this or another method, reconnect in an efficient way? Any improvements in this code is welcome as well. `ExtClient` does not reconnect on its own and is a global variable.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using [mymysql](https://github.com/ziutek/mymysql) then you can use the [auto reconnection interface](https://github.com/ziutek/mymysql#example-6---autoreconn-interface).

From the docs

```
import (
    "github.com/ziutek/mymysql/autorc"
    _ "github.com/ziutek/mymysql/thrsafe" // You may also use the native engine
)

// [...]

db := autorc.New("tcp", "", "127.0.0.1:3306", user, pass, dbname)

// Initilisation commands. They will be executed after each connect.
db.Register("set names utf8")

// There is no need to explicity connect to the MySQL server
rows, res, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM R")
checkError(err)

// Now we are connected.

// It does not matter if connection will be interrupted during sleep, eg
// due to server reboot or network down.
```

That said, from reading the [sql docs](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/) and [sql driver docs](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/driver/) and the associated code, it looks like that if the SQL driver returns `ErrBadConn` then the sql package will retry with a new connection.  This was only added in July 2012 so perhaps isn't well supported by SQL drivers yet.

Comment: I looking for a library independent solution, but maybe it's quite simple, the driver should handle reconnects.

Comment: I would expect the driver to handle reconnects.  That is how it works in other languages I have used like python.  The driver has more domain specific knowledge so should be able to do it better.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ExtClient has a Connect or Reconnect method.

And also assuming that the BrokenPipe err is exported as a variable that you can match agains.

Then this should work `if err == BrokenPipeErr { ExtClient.Connect(args ...SomeType) }`

Those are a lot of assumptions though so you should probably tell us a little bit more information like what database you are connecting to. Which client lib you are using. And other such information.

Comment: Yeah, the client library is quite stupid, I don't want to discuss that particular library. Should the driver handle reconnects then. Maybe it's that simple. The Request-method knows about the error before I do so I guess it could do something about it aswell.